# How to pass an empty string to a Date type column through hibernate

Tags: java, sql, oracle, hibernate

I am trying to pass an empty string that is `""` to a Date type column `Logout_date` through hibernate:

```
query.setParameter(3, "");
```

But an exception is thrown :

```
java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.util.Date.
```

How can I achieve this.?

**EDIT:**

```
String updq2 = "update TblUser a set loggedStatus = ? ,lockedStatus= ?,currentAttempts = ?,logoutDate = ? where upper(a.id)=?";//,lockedStatus= ?, currentAttempts = ?, logoutDate = ? where upper(a.id) = ?";
            Session newSession2=factory.openSession();
            Transaction tx1=newSession2.beginTransaction();
            Query query =newSession2.createQuery(updq2);
            query.setParameter(0, (byte)9);
            query.setParameter(1,"1" );
            query.setParameter(2, 0);
            query.setParameter(3, "");
            query.setParameter(4,  userName.toUpperCase());
query.executeUpdate();
tx1.commit();
newSession2.close();
```

Comment: if the field is nullable there is no need to call setParameter.

Comment: You can not pass astring to a date.

Comment: i need to insert (null) in my Table and i was able to do this through JDBC.@Jens

Comment: @StefanBeike what if i am updating and i want to have that value as (null)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. If your inserting data to your database and the database allows `null` values for that column just don't set that parameter in your query. In this case it's automatically set to `null`.
2. If your having an update statement and want to set an existing value to `null` you could try something like that:

   ```
   query.setParameter(3, PreparedStatement.setNull());
   ```

Hope that helps!

**EDIT:**

```
    String updq2;
    bool isNull = false;
    //If your data is null and you want to set it null use this 
    if(yourDate == null)
    {
        updq2 = "update TblUser a set loggedStatus = ? ,lockedStatus= ?,currentAttempts = ?,logoutDate = NULL where upper(a.id)=?";//,lockedStatus= ?, currentAttempts = ?, logoutDate = ? where upper(a.id) = ?";
        isNull = true;
    } //If it isn't null and you want to set and value use this
    else
    {
        updq2 = "update TblUser a set loggedStatus = ? ,lockedStatus= ?,currentAttempts = ?,logoutDate = ? where upper(a.id)=?";//,lockedStatus= ?, currentAttempts = ?, logoutDate = ? where upper(a.id) = ?";

    } 

    Session newSession2=factory.openSession();
    Transaction tx1=newSession2.beginTransaction();
    Query query =newSession2.createQuery(updq2);
    query.setParameter(0, (byte)9);
    query.setParameter(1,"1" );
    query.setParameter(2, 0);

    if(isNull)
    {
         query.setParameter(3,  userName.toUpperCase());
    }
    else
    {
         query.setParameter(3, yourDataHere);
         query.setParameter(4,  userName.toUpperCase());
    }
```

Comment: Thanks thats fine for inserting but what if i am updating and need to set that as (null)

Comment: @VishalTyagi see the second part(2.-) I think that should solve your problem

Comment: Mhhh okay... Could you please post the rest of your code using query?

Comment: @VishalTyagi Is the date always null when the code-snippet above is executed? If so you could wirt NULL direkcty to your SQL-Statement. Otherwise you could check with and if-clause

Comment: isnt there any way i can set it in setparameter

Comment: @FelixGerber  What about dynamic insert query? I am dynamically forming a insert query in the java code

Answer (score 1):

The best practice would be You check if date is null. If null you should avoid adding parameter for null value of type date. Hibernate does not automatically convert string to date.

Comment: actually no need to set null explicitly, default will be null

Comment: the column is nullable .